# How to Javascript to load a CSS file only for one specific page?

Tags: javascript, css, netsuite

I am working on a shopping cart on Netsuite coded with nested tables... I know it sucks.

Because I only have access to fields to customize the website I need a JS snippet to be able to load a specific CSS file for the shopping cart (to avoid styling the rest of the website)

I have never done that before, here is how I would start:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var path = window.location.pathname;
if(path.indexOf('/Cart') !=-1 {
  // load css file
}
</script>
```

What code would do that for me?

Comment: Would a document.write work? `document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from closing your `if(...` with a `)`, this should get you going:

```
var styles = document.createElement("link");
styles.rel = "stylesheet";
styles.type = "text/css";
styles.href = "file.css";  // your file's URL
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styles);
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @user883356 great glad to help :) you should hit the little checkmark to accept the answer too if you don't mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

While testing the url does work there is a better way to add tab and category specific markup.

In your website theme in the "Additions to Head" section add a tag `<TAB_ADDONS>` and add that to the site builder Tags but with a blank body

Then go to your list of tabs and find the shopping cart tab.
Edit it and select Tag Overrides
find TAB_ADDONS and enter:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file.css">
```

you'd use the root relative url for the href.

This keeps your theme much cleaner and allows arbitrary code inclusions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does sound like it is really how Netsuite work, i will try this on Monday. 

Also, if you have any advice, thoughts on how to style the whole shopping car/account/checkout in Site Builder (not the advanced) i will be really interested! Thanks!